# Handle drag shape that be overlap

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

i 'm doing  a program that user could drag this shape.
The shape is:
[image: IF shape]
[image: Action Shape]

It could be joined each other for making new block. 
But the problem is, when i drag two [Blue] Shape into the [If] Shape, i cant not drag the [Blue] anymore, cause of the [If] Shape is collapsed and make the [Blue] Shape cant not be interact.
[image]

Here is my code:
The define of the shape

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleCode.ActionShape"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleCode"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="colorToBrushConverter"/>
        <local:ThicknessConverter x:Key="thicknessConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Path Data="{Binding SvgData}"
              Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}"
              Cursor="Hand">
        </Path>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding TextColor, Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Margin="{Binding MarginText}" Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleCode.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleCode"
    Title="" 
    Width="1400"
    Height="800"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BaseShapeMVVm}">
            <local:ActionShape AllowDrop="True" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove" MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp"></local:ActionShape>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView  Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

could you give me some recommendation for this problem? i 'm very appoxiated

Comment: I am sorry but your question is very difficult to understand. Do you mind to improve it?

Comment: You should expand the tree node on mouse over. Have you tried this?